# Carting ADD-TO-CART button is not getting data in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

**Add-to-Cart**
I am getting output but it is not getting data to add-to-cart button

```
Cart {#196 ▼
  +items: null
  +totalQty: 0
  +totalprice: 0
}
```

cart:

```
<?php

namespace App;


class Cart 
{
    public $items = null;
    public $totalQty = 0;
    public $totalprice = 0;

    public function __construct($oldCart)
    {
        if($oldCart){
            $this->items = $oldCart->items;
            $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
            $this->totalprice = $oldCart->totalprice; 
        }
    }

    public function add($item, $id)
    {
        $storedItem = ['Qty'=>0, 'price'=>$item->price, 'item'=>$item];

        if($this->items){
            if(array_key_exists($id,$this->items))
            {
                $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
            }
            $storedItem['qty']++;
            $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];

            $this->items['$id'] = $storedItem;
            $this->totalQty++;
            $this->totalprice += $item->price;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function getAddtoCart(Request $request, $id)
{
    //return 'hello';

    $product = Product::find($id);

    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($product); die();

    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;

    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->add($product, $product->id);

    $request->session()->put('cart',$cart);
    dd(($request->session()->get('cart')));

    return redirect('/Carting_page');

}
```

When user check a box or boxes, and presses 'add to cart' I'd like the item to display on

please solve my problem I am not getting this method, I am trying to solve my problem...

Comment: Your output suggests that null is being passed to add() function of your cart.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you're not instantiating the item attribute of the controller as an array. Try to change:

```
public $items = null;
```

into

```
public $items = array();
```

and then when you add items to your array, you don't want to assign '$id' as a literal key, but as a variable key to the array:

```
$this->items['$id'] = $storedItem;
```

should be:

```
$this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
```

Comment: output is given same here 
Cart      
   {#195 ▼
  +items: []
  +totalQty: 0
  +totalprice: 0
}

Comment: What happens if you dump/log (for example using the logging Facade) directly after the Models' add method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Cart.php`

```
   public $quantity = 0;
   public $total = 0;

   public function __construct($oldCart)
   {
    if($oldCart){
        $this->items = $oldCart->items;
        $this->quantity = $oldCart->quantity;
        $this->total = $oldCart->total;
    }
   }

   public function add($item, $id)
   {
    $storedItem = ['quantity' => 0, 'price' => $item->price, 'item' => $item];

    if($this->items){
        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
            $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
        }
    }

    $storedItem['quantity']++;
    $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['quantity'];
    $this->quantity++;
    $this->total += $item->price;
    $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
   }
```

`CartController.php`

```
   public function getProduct(Request $request, $id)
   {
      $product = Product::find($id);
      $size = $request->get('size');
      $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
      $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
      $cart->add($product, $product->id);
      $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
      return back();

   }
```

`web.php`

`Route::post('add/{id}', 'Products\CartController@getProduct')->name('cart.add');`

OR

`Route::get('add/{id}', 'Products\CartController@getProduct')->name('cart.add');`

Comment: Add too

`public $items;`

over
```public $quantity = 0;
   public $total = 0;```